# If H contained in the normalizer of P, then HP is a subgroup of the normalizer.

Tags: group-theory

I read the following proposition and am trying to prove it, but haven't been able to. Could any one help me out with this one?

Let $P$ be p-Sylow subgroup of G. Suppose first that H is contained in the normalizer of P. Prove that HP is a subgroup of the normalizer and P is normal in HP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This results from this well-known result:

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$, $K$ a *normal* subgroup. Then  $HK=KH$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Indeed if $\;hk, h'k\in HK\;$ ($h,h'\in H$, $k,k'\in K$), we have
\begin{align*}
(hk)(h'k')&=h(kh')k'=h(h'l)k'\enspace\text{for some}\enspace l\in K\\
&=(hh')(lk)\in HK
\end{align*}
Similarly $\;(hk)^{-1}=k^{-1}h^{-1}\in KH=HK$.

Now, for the present situation, $H$ and $P$ are subgroups of the normaliser $N_G(P)$, and $P$ is normal in $N_G(P)$, hence by the previous result, $HP$ is a subgroup of $N_G(P)$.

Answer (score 1):

The first part is trivial and it is *always* true: if $\;G\;$ is a group and we have sugroups such that $\;A,B,C\le G\;,\;\; B,C\le A\implies BC\subset A\;$, no matter whether $\;BC\;$ is a subgroup or not.

In this case, $\;P, H\le N_G(P)\implies PH\le N_G(P)\;$ , and $\;PH\;$ is a subgroup because trivially $\;P\lhd N_G(P)\;$ (Remember: if $\;A,B\le G\;$ , then $\;AB\;$ is a subgroup iff $\;AB=BA\;$ . This happens, in particular, if either $\;A,B\;$ is normal.)

Now, for *any* $\;h\in H,\;x,y\in P\;$ we have

$$x^{hy}:=y^{-1}h^{-1}xhy=y^{-1}\,\overbrace{\overline x}^{\in P}\, y\in P\implies P\lhd HP$$

because $\;h\in N_G(P)\implies p^h\in P\;\;\forall\,p\in P\;$